# How to unselect multiple UITableview cell by tapping the selected button again

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, radio-button

[image: Mulitple Selection List]
Hi, I wanted to select multiple UITableViewCells and unselect any by tapping again.

Following are my codes of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`: and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
NSString *cellIdentifier = @"serviceTypeSelectionCell";
ServiceTypeSelectionTableViewCell *serviceTypeCell = (ServiceTypeSelectionTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];  
if (serviceTypeCell == nil)
{
    serviceTypeCell = [[ServiceTypeSelectionTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
//serviceDetailsCell.noOfQuantityTextField.tag = indexPath.row;
serviceTypeCell.serviceTypeNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",arrayOfServiceTypes[indexPath.row][@"sub_cat_name"]];

if([[arrayOfSelectedBoolValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue])
{
    serviceTypeCell.serviceTypeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cancellation_reason_correct_icon"];
}
else {
    serviceTypeCell.serviceTypeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cancellation_reason_unselect_icon"];
}
return serviceTypeCell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
for (int i = 0; i < [arrayOfServiceTypes count]; i++)//Make all Rows To UnSelected
{
   [arrayOfSelectedBoolValues replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
}
[arrayOfSelectedBoolValues addObjectsFromArray:sele:indexPath.row];
if(arrayOfSelectedBoolValues!=nil)
{
    [arrayOfSelectedBoolValues replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
}

    [arrayOfSelectedBoolValues replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
{
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self showOrHideAddButton];
}
```

I have an existing code of single select and unselect of the above uitableview. And I can get multiple selection only by disabling all the above code and keep this part in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 [arrayOfSelectedBoolValues replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self showOrHideAddButton];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.doneButton.hidden = YES;
    arrayOfSelectedBoolValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [arrayOfServiceTypes count]; i++)
    {
        // [arrayOfexpOrCollBoolValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        [arrayOfSelectedBoolValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    }
    [self sendServiceToGetServiceTypes];
}
```

so please anyone post a structured code according to my code to select multiple tableviewcells and unselect any cells by tapping again before send selected values to the server.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can check this one. This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302732/tableview-with-checkbox

Comment: @ZaheerUdeen  This is the exact one I wanted. Thanks, I will have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your didSelectRowAtIndexPath like

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    if (_selectedIndexes == nil) {
        self.selectedIndexes = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    if ([_selectedIndexes containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [_selectedIndexes removeObject:indexPath];

    } else {
        [_selectedIndexes addObject:indexPath];

    }
     [self.tableView reloadData];
       [self showOrHideAddButton];

    }
```

And in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` try modifying the code to change the `serviceTypeImageView` image like

```
if([_selectedIndexes containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        serviceTypeCell.serviceTypeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cancellation_reason_correct_icon"];
    }
    else {
        serviceTypeCell.serviceTypeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cancellation_reason_unselect_icon"];
    }
```

Here `selectedIndexes` is a mutable array that keeps track of the selected indexPaths

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *selectedIndexes;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do in this way:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
/// first run a loop for deselect all data
//Make all Rows To UnSelected
for (int i = 0; i < [arrayOfServiceTypes count]; i++)
{
   [arrayOfSelectedBoolValues replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

}

Now which one you have selected you need to do like this:

[arrayOfSelectedBoolValues replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

I hope it will help your problem.

Comment: This is the same method in the existing code. It will handle only single selection and if I want to select other option it will unselect the previous one and selects the second one.

Comment: This is not I wanted. What I want is select multiple cells first and unselect any of tablecell which I selected by tapping again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain an array of rows you select, based on that you will either select a row or will deselect row(if it already exists in that array). Would look something like this:

Swift 3 Code:

```
var selectedArray : [IndexPath] = [IndexPath]()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let myCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableCell

    if(!selectedArray.contains(indexPath))
    {
        selectedArray.append(indexPath)
        // Change cell image for selected if needed here.
    }
    else
    {
        // remove from array here if required
        // Change cell image for un selected if needed here.
    }
}
```

Objc Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

.
.
.
if(![selectedArray containsObject:indexPath])
{
    [selectedArray addObject:indexPath];
    // Change cell image for selected if needed here.
}
else
{
    [selectedArray removeObject:indexPath];
    // remove from array here if required
    // Change cell image for un selected if needed here.
}
.
.
.
}
```

Declare `selectedArray` in .h file (in interface) and initialize it in `viewDidLoad` like so - `selectedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`

Comment: Hi Abdul can you provide me the exact code in objective-c ?

Comment: I used the following method, similar to what you wrote. but still it's not worked.   
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    
    
    if([arrayOfSelectedBoolValues containsObject:indexPath])
    {
       
       [arrayOfSelectedBoolValues replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    }
    else
    {
        [arrayOfSelectedBoolValues replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    }